# Android Studio (Kotlin) - User has to log back into app every time app is closed

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

So i have a `RegisterActivity` and a `MapsActivity`.
When a new user opens the app, they will be on the `RegisterActivity` and sign up. Once they sign up, my app creates an `Intent` and sends them to the `MapsActivity`

The problem is whenever the user closes the app, they have to login/register again.

I want the the app to be able to open back to the `MapsActivity` since the user has not signed out yet

---

Here's my attempt:

i put an `<intent-filter>` in both `RegisterActivity` and `MapsActivity` because i think both should both be the main launchers depending if a user is logged in or not right?

- If they aren't logged in, then the main launcher should be `RegisterActivity`
- If they are logged in, then the main launcher should be `MapsActivity`

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    <activity android:name=".MapsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
    </activity>

</application>
```

**MapsActivity.kt**

```
public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    if(currentUser == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "User is not logged in")
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
    }else {
        Log.d(TAG, "User is logged in")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use a listener. Let's assume you have two activities, the `LoginActivity` and the `MainActivity`. The listener that can be created in the `LoginActivity` should look like this:

```
val authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
    val firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

This basically means that if the user is logged in, skip the `LoginActivity` and go to the `MainActivity`.

Instantiate the `FirebaseAuth` object:

```
val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```

And start listening for changes in your `onStart()` method like this:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    firebaseAuth!!.addAuthStateListener(this.authStateListener!!)
}
```

In the `MainActivity`, you should do the same thing:

```
val authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
    val firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Which basically means that if the user is not logged in, skip the `MainActivity` and go to the `LoginActivity`. In this activity you should do the same thing as in the `LoginActivity`, you should start listening for changes in the `onStart()`.

In both activities, don't forget to remove the listener in the moment in which is not needed anymore. So add the following line of code in your `onStop()` method:

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    firebaseAuth!!.removeAuthStateListener(this.authStateListener!!)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with one database class? I want to keep my code organized and one of the things I want to do is keep anything related to Firestore in one single DB class.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have developer a similar app and I simply use a splash screen that checks if the users is logged or not and then open the right screen.
The splash doesn't need to be to complex: in fact you can even avoid to set a view and just check whatever you want.
[This article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) explains it very clearly.

Remember to call finish() on the splash activity after launching the right one.

Comment: ouh this looks nice. i'll give that a try tommorow