# How can i make FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener work in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val firebaseAuthListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
        val user = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid
        user?.let {
            startActivity(HomeActivity.newIntent(this))
            finish()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        loginProgressLayout.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> true }
    }

    fun onLogin(v: View) {
        var proceed = true
        if (emailET.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            emailTIL.error = "email is required"
            emailTIL.isErrorEnabled = true
            proceed = false
        }
        if(passwordET.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            passwordTIL.error = "password is required"
            passwordTIL.isErrorEnabled = true
            proceed = false
        }
        if(proceed){
            loginProgressLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailET.text.toString(), passwordET.text.toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (!task.isSuccessful){
                        loginProgressLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "LoginError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    exception.printStackTrace()
                    loginProgressLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                }
        }
    } //onLogin end
```

I checked I got something authentication number from `firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` code line.
But my question is about the property `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener`, which doesn't work. 
When I get authentication number and then I want the `AuthStateListener` to work!

I read the Firebase API, but it didn't work. How can I make `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `addAuthStateListener` with your listener in order for it to work.

So for example in the `onStart` of your activity:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    firebaseAuth!!.addAuthStateListener(this.firebaseAuthListener!!)
}
```

I recommend studying this answer (more): [Android Studio (Kotlin) - User has to log back into app every time app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046250/android-studio-kotlin-user-has-to-log-back-into-app-every-time-app-is-closed/54050040#54050040)

Comment: private val firebaseAuthListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
        val user = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid
        user?.let {
            startActivity(HomeActivity.newIntent(this))
            finish()
        }
    }

Comment: only this code "FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener" dosen't work.  i made a dummy authentication in Firebase and i wanted to log in but it didn't work! the other day, i made it with same way, but today it didn't work..

Comment: If it doesn't work, you did something differently. For example, the code in your question doesn't call `addAuthStateListener` for the listener, which is required if you want it to be called.

Comment: override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        firebaseAuth!!.addAuthStateListener {this.firebaseAuthListener!! }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener {firebaseAuthListener }
    }

Comment: i added those 2 code in my project, but it doesn't still work. and i initialized firebaseAuthListener property, then , the FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener always knows a change about Firebase authentication automatically. isn't it?? i don't know where i should  call addAuthStateListener ....

Comment: i found out i useed  { } instead of ( ), that's why the code didn't work. now it's working!!